# Migrating from system() to a shellexecute() command problems

Tags: c++, string, shellexecute

How can pass from this instruction;

```
string copyDir = "copy \"%AppData%\\..\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\" + chromeX[count] + "\\Login Data\" \"%AppData%\\..\\Local" + newLoc;
system(copyDir.c_str());
```

To a `ShellExecute()`? I have some problem with the parameters inside.

I tried this;

```
ShellExecute(NULL, "open", copyDir.c_str(), NULL, NULL, SW_NORMAL);
```

But it's not working.

Comment: What is the error that you receive?

Comment: Since copy is a shell command in windows you need to call it using "cmd /c copy" from outside.

Comment: Niall i didt got any error but the txt file is empty as output runnign it the function shellexecute but with system() is working as well!

Comment: Any reason you can't just call `CopyFile` or similar?

Comment: passing string value to shellexecute code it causese the bug....i should think to convert the string value to char due to the API returns...anyway still working with system().

Comment: @Mohammadyou meant this?string newLoc= "\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\" + chromeX[count] + "\\Login1";
const char *newLocation =  newLoc.c_str();
string copyDir = "copy \"%AppData%\\..\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\" + chromeX[count] + "\\Login Data\" \"%AppData%\\..\\Local"+newLoc;
 
 
ShellExecute(NULL,"open","C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",copyDir.c_str(), NULL, SW_NORMAL);